# Google BigQuery: How to use gsutil to either remove or overwrite a table?

Tags: google-bigquery, gsutil

I have a program which will download some data from the web and save it as a `csv`, and then upload that data to a `Google Cloud Storage Bucket`. Next, that program will use `gsutil` to create a new `Google BigQuery Table` by concatenating all the files in the  `Google Cloud Storage Bucket`. To do the concatenating I run this command in `command prompt`:

```
bq load --project_id=ib-17   da.hi   gs://ib/hi/*  da:TIMESTAMP,bol:STRING,bp:FLOAT,bg:FLOAT,bi:FLOAT,lo:FLOAT,en:FLOAT,kh:FLOAT,ow:FLOAT,ls:FLOAT
```

The issue is that for some reason this command appends to the existing table, so I get a lot of duplicate data. The question is how can I either use `gsutil` to delete the table first maybe how can I use `gsutil` to overwrite the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you should delete and recreate the table with:

```
bq rm -f -t da.hi
bq mk --schema da:TIMESTAMP,bol:STRING,bp:FLOAT,bg:FLOAT,bi:FLOAT,lo:FLOAT,en:FLOAT,kh:FLOAT,ow:FLOAT,ls:FLOAT -t da.hi
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The only way to improve this would be to add the project_id, so the command would look like: `bq rm -f -t --project_id=ib-17  da.hi`

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the `--replace` flag, such as:

```
bq load --replace --project_id=ib-17   da.hi   gs://ib/hi/*
```

I think that this flag was once called [WRITE_DISPOSITION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.writeDisposition) but looks like the CLI updated the name to `--replace`.